# How can I maintain a streaming value and be 95% confident that the measure for the population dropped below some value?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sequential-analysis

I weigh hail stones one at a time, producing a sequence of weights.

I want to tell the weatherman when I'm 95% confident that hail stones are less than 50g in weight based on the previous $K$ hail stones I caught.

Is there an efficient way to maintain a streaming value for this? I was thinking about maintaining a streaming median, but I'm not sure how to gauge the confidence for that.

Comment: What do you mean by streaming value? what information is available about each hail stone? Do you end up with a sequence $h_1,\ldots,h_n$ of stone weights?

Comment: Exactly. I get a sequence of stone weights. I was wondering if I could use the previous $K$ stone weights to determine whether stone weights in general are under 50g.

Comment: I still do not get it: what is so special about $K$? Is it a random variable? a stopping rule? Else you can definitely use your $K$ observations to test whether the _average_ weight is less than $50$g. To test that all of them are less than $50$g does not require statistics or confidence.

Comment: I interpret the question like this: you sample hailstone weights sequentially. How can you determine when to stop sampling them and report that the median of the entire population is less than 50g with 95% confidence? (Obviously you cannot apply a standard test of median at each step, because the tests are highly correlated and their p-values are subject to large multiple comparisons errors.)  Is this interpretation correct?  Instead of "median" should I perhaps understand some upper quantile (so that you are asserting nearly all the hailstones are less than 50g)? (cc @Xi'an)

Comment: @whuber, exactly! Thanks for clarifying. Interesting you mention that I can't apply a standard test of median at each step ... I was thinking about doing something similar - a hypothesis test for each window of hail stones I receive at the 95% confidence level.

Comment: For an overview, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis and for more details visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_probability_ratio_test.  A classic paper in this area is freely available at http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177731118 (Wald, 1945).